# Binding HTML links to cells in AG-Grid

Tags: mysql, reactjs, web, ag-grid

I am developing a website containing a table in the format of the image below.  I would like to make it so that when a user clicks any cell within the row of a given child, they are routed to a new page containing a more detailed profile of that child.  I already have programmed a system of creating unique HTML links for each child page using their ID.  How do I go about binding these links to each row within the AG Grid so that when a cell within the row for a given child is clicked a user will be led to that child's page?

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MN9yX.png)

Comment: See [ask], and especially [mcve]. The idea is you describe what you want to do, show what you tried, and tell us what results you get. Reproduce your issue on plunk or stackblitz so that others can help you easily.

Comment: have you tried row clicked event ? onRowClicked: function(params) {
        // console.log("Callback onRowClicked: " + (params.data?params.data.name:null) + " - " + params.event);
    },

Answer (score 0):

In gridOption, there is a property called **onRowClicked**:

```
gridOptions = {
   ...
   onRowClicked: event => this.onRowClicked(event)
}

private onRowClicked({node, data}: any) {
   // Do your logic, the data is the row data, it should contain the ID information you need
}
```